# How to activate a crossed out character described as "surrogate high, non private use"?

Tags: fonts

I'm editing a `woff` font file using FontForge, and I would like to add a glyph for the unicode character [0xD835](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1d44e/index.htm).

However the box for this character has 2 crosses, one for the glyph and one for the unicode char (while usually there is only 1 cross for the glyph), moreover its description in the top bar is "surrogate high, non private use" (what does this mean?), see images below

[image]

[image]

I tried copying a glyph from another character and pasting it into the 0xD835 box, obtaining this

[image]

but the character is not displaying when I use it.

Moreover, if I click on "glyph info" then FontForge crashes.

Is it possibile to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`D835`+`DC4E` = `1D44E`, that is the first two are surrogate codes used in pair in the UTF-16 encoding to resolve a number greater than 16 bits.

So the proper way to add a glyph is to edit `1D44E`, not `D835` and/or `DC4E`.

Click on Encoding > Reencode > ISO 10646-1 (Unicode, Full).
The list of glyphs is now much larger, search for `0x0001D44E` and past there the glyph.